# How to create a new value with information from multiple columns?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have dataset that has columns that need to be sorted based on multiple columns.

The first column contains a name and the second a number, the names are not unique. What I want is a NewID from 1 to 10 per name based on the descending value of the number.
Like this:
[image: example]

Any ideas how this can be done? Preferably in ArcMap.

Comment: Do you need a python script or step by step algorithm as an answer?

Comment: Python script that can be used in field calculator would be nice.

Comment: ArcMap and FME require different solutions, which makes this question *too broad*. A Python solution requires you to provide the code you've developed to date. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: I removed FME, I currently do not have a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you removed FME but for the record, a Sorter, sorting by the NameID and then secondly the number, followed by a Counter with the Counter ID set to the value of the NameID attribute will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is will not answer your question but it might help you to solve your problem.
Here is how to sort lists in python:

```
import pprint
table = [
    [1,'H',-1],
    [2,'D',2],
    [3,'D',8],
    [4,'D',1],
    [5,'H',68],
    [6,'H',97],
    [7,'H',88],
]

print 'Before sorting:'
print '[OBJECTID, NameID, Number]'
pprint.pprint(table)
print 

print 'After sorting:'
print '[OBJECTID, NameID, Number]'
pprint.pprint(
    sorted(table, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[2]))
    )
```

Excetuting this script gives:

```
Before sorting:
[OBJECTID, NameID, Number]
[[1, 'H', -1],
 [2, 'D', 2],
 [3, 'D', 8],
 [4, 'D', 1],
 [5, 'H', 68],
 [6, 'H', 97],
 [7, 'H', 88]]

After sorting:
[OBJECTID, NameID, Number]
[[4, 'D', 1],
 [2, 'D', 2],
 [3, 'D', 8],
 [1, 'H', -1],
 [5, 'H', 68],
 [7, 'H', 88],
 [6, 'H', 97]]
```